# Bijection between $(0,1)$ to $(1,2)\cup (3,4)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> How to find a bijection from $(0,1)$ to $(1,2)\cup(3,4)$?

Firstly, I broke $(0,1)$ into $(0,\frac{1}{2})\cup[\frac{1}{2},1)$ and then mapped separately. Problem is that I couldn't find a bijection from $[\frac{1}{2},1)$ to $(3,4).$

Comment: Take a linear function to map one interval to another.

Comment: Take a look at the Related questions at the bottom right

Comment: @Wuestenfux but $\frac{1}{2}$ is included in first set while $3$ is not

Comment: Take out a sequence from each interval and map the sequences.

Answer (score 2):

The 'standard' approach to finding a bijection between a half-open interval $[a,b)$ and an open interval $(c,d)$ is as follows. First biject $[a,b)$ with $[0,1)$ and $(c,d)$ with $(0,1)$ using linear functions; this reduces the problem to finding a bijection from $[0,1)$ to $(0,1)$.

Now pick an infinite sequence $(x_n)_{n \ge 0}$ in $(0,1)$, and define a function $[0,1) \to (0,1)$, which sends $0$ to $x_0$, sends each $x_n$ to $x_{n+1}$, and sends each remaining element of $[0,1)$ to itself.

You now need to make this description into a precise definition of a function (and, in particular, choose the sequence $(x_n)_{n \ge 0}$), and prove that the function is a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's brainstorm (or let me pretend we are brainstorming while I lead you to a standard Mathematician's Trick).

We *know* they have the same cardinality so a bijection must exist.  And we know how to do a bijection from $(\frac 34,1)$ to $(3,4)$, so what seems to be our problem?  Well, we have an extra point $\frac 34$ that just doesn't fit into the other.

So this seems to be an issue of how do we find a bijection between an infinite set, and an infinite set plus an extra point.  i.e. between $X$ and $X \cup \{a\}; a \not \in X$.

Well, we can always shove $a$ to some $x_a$ and leave the rest alone.  But then what happens to $x_a$? We have to shove that to some different ${x_a}_2$.  And ${x_a}_2$ to some ${x_a}_3$, etc.  As $X$ is infinite we can do this... supposedly.  So we will get a countably infinite chain of $a\rightarrow x_1; x_i\rightarrow x_{i+1}$.  And all the rest of the values of $X$ simply map to themselves.

Example.  The bijection from $\mathbb N \cup \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb N$ can be $0\rightarrow 1$ and $i \rightarrow i + 1$.  Easy-peasy.

Deceptively simple: The bijection from $(0, \infty)$ to $[0, \infty)$ is $0\rightarrow 1$ and $i \in \mathbb N \rightarrow i+1$ and for $x \not \in \mathbb N$ we do $x \rightarrow x$.

So that was the hard part.  The rest is boot strapping and shuffling.

How would we do this for a bounded set?  $[0, 1)\rightarrow (0,1)$?

Well, we need a bounded series $a\rightarrow x_1 \rightarrow x_2 \rightarrow...$.  So what inifinite series can we use?  Well, the answer is any one we like. what comes to *my* mind is $\frac 12 \rightarrow \frac 34 \rightarrow \frac 78 ....$

So $k:[0,1) \rightarrow (0,1)$ via $k(0) = 12$ and $k(\frac {2^n -1}{2^n}) = \frac {2^{n+1} -1}{2^n}$ and $k(x) = x$ otherwise.

So $h:[\frac 12, 1) \rightarrow (3,4)$ via $h(x) = 2x + 2$ if $x \ne \frac {2^n -1}{2^n}$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$.  $h(\frac {2^n -1}{2^n}) = 2*\frac {2^{n+1} -1}{2^{n+1}}+2$ is a bijectiona.  Which we can simplify as $h(\frac {2^n -1}{2^n}) = \frac {2^{n+2} -1}{2^{n}}$.